# Is it possible to backup a 6-node DataStax Enterprise cluster and restore it to a new 4-node cluster?

Tags: cassandra, restore, datastax-enterprise

I have this case. We have 6 nodes DSE cluster and the task is to back it up, and restore all the keyspaces, tables and data into a new cluster. But this new cluster has only 4 nodes.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is definitely possible to do this. This operation is more commonly referred to as "cloning" -- you are copying the data from one [DataStax Enterprise (DSE)](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise) cluster to another.

There is a Cassandra utility called `sstableloader` which reads the SSTables and loads it to a cluster even when the destination cluster's topology is not identical to the source.

I have previously documented the procedure in [How to migrate data in tables to a new Cassandra cluster](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/316520/) which is also applicable to DSE clusters. Cheers!